# Simple MVC DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I need a dropdownlist to be populate with a simple list of numbers. I'm not sure if I can do this without having to create a new SelectList since it's just numbers.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberPassengers, new SelectList(Model.NumberPassengers))
```

Really not sure what to do in my model:

```
public int[] Passengers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Comment: Is the list of values always the same static set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a new List of `SelectListItem`. I normally then drop this in the ViewBag for things liek this because you don't want it back. Then bind it to your a `DropDownListFor` control, here's one I've done for times:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PopulateTimes()
            {
                List<SelectListItem> timeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                for (int count = 0; count < 24; count++)
                {
                    timeList.Add(new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Value = count.ToString("00"),
                        Text = count.ToString("00") + ":00",
                        Selected = count == 9,
                    });
                }
                return timeList;
            }
```

then

```
ViewBag.DepartureTimes = PopulateTimes();
```

Then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartureTime, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DepartureTimes)
```